# Is the order in which parameters are passed to a Perl subroutine significant?

Tags: perl

Is the order in which parameters are passed to a Perl subroutine significant? When I debugged the following code:

```
my $loopCounter = 1;
foreach(@authors) {

   my @splitAffiliations = splitAffiliations($params);
   my @foundItems = findAffiliationForAuthor($_, @splitAffiliations, $loopCounter);

   # Process @foundItems

   $loopCounter++;
}

...

sub findAffiliationForAuthor {

   my ($author, @affiliations, $aIndex) = @_;

   ...
}
```

I found that the variable `$loopCounter` had a value immediately before the subroutine `findAffiliationForAuthor` was called, but was undefined after the call. So, the subroutine received values for the first two parameters and nothing for the third. But, when I changed the order of the parameters to:

```
my @foundItems = findAffiliationForAuthor($loopCounter, $_, @splitAffiliations);
```

The value of `$loopCounter` was retained and passed the subroutine as expected.

It looks like I have to put all my scalar variables before my array variables, or maybe not mix them. Does that sound right?

Comment: Succinctly, yes — the order matters. Note that you cannot pass any arguments after the array; `$aIndex` will always be `undef` and `@affiliations` will absorb any argument intended to be in `$aIndex`.  And yes, all scalars must appear before any array, and you can only have one array.  References are disinct, of course — they're like scalars (are a special case of scalar).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly the order matters.

Arguments are passed in the order in which you pass them, and an array argument is *flattened* into the argument list. The argument list appears inside the subroutine as the contents of the `@_` list.

You can't actually pass an array as an argument; its elements are extracted and shoved into the list with any other arguments.

The problem you're having is because of the way you're processing the arguments:

```
my ($author, @affiliations, $aIndex) = @_;
```

`$author` gets the first element of `@_`, as you intended, but `@affiliations` slurps up all the rest of the list. The value `undef` is then stored in `$aIndex`.

You can pass a *single* array to a subroutine as long as it's the last argument:

```
my($first_scalar, $second_scalar, @array) = @_;
```

If you pass multiple arrays to a subroutine:

```
foo(@array1, @array2);
```

the elements of both arrays are flattened into a single list, and there's no way for the subroutine to know which elements came from which array argument.

You can pass *references* to arrays:

```
sub foo {
    my ($scalar1, $array_ref1, $scalar2, $array_ref2) = @_;
    # ...
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
foo(42, \@array1, $some_scalar, \@array2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Subroutines take a list of scalars as arguments. If you build the argument list from an array, the contents of the array will be passed.

```
$ perl -E'sub f { say "$_: $_[$_]" for 0..$#_; }  f("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")'
0: a
1: b
2: c
3: d
4: e

$ perl -E'sub f { say "$_: $_[$_]" for 0..$#_; }  @a = ("b"); f("a", @a, "c", "d", "e")'
0: a
1: b
2: c
3: d
4: e

$ perl -E'sub f { say "$_: $_[$_]" for 0..$#_; }  @a = ("b", "c"); f("a", @a, "d", "e")'
0: a
1: b
2: c
3: d
4: e
```

Now you assign the argument list (the contents of `@_`) to

```
($author, @affiliations, $aIndex)
```

How many of the scalars should it assign to `@affiliations`? You could say all but the first and the last, but then you have to come up for a new rule for

```
my (@a, @b) = @_;
```

To keep it simple, Perl always assigns all of the remaining scalars to the first array in the list. This works fine if the array is the last element, but not otherwise.

If you want to pass an array to a sub, the best way is to pass a reference to it.

```
$ perl -E'sub f { say "$_: $_[$_]" for 0..$#_; }  @a = ("b", "c"); f("a", \@a, "d", "e")'
0: a
1: ARRAY(0x14ff8d0)
2: d
3: e
```